# R: How to efficiently find out whether data.frame A is contained in data.frame B?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, set-intersection

In order to find out whether data frame `df.a` is a subset of data frame `df.b` I did the following:

```
df.a <- data.frame( x=1:5, y=6:10 )
df.b <- data.frame( x=1:7, y=6:12 )
inds.x <- as.integer( lapply( df.a$x, function(x) which(df.b$x == x) ))
inds.y <- as.integer( lapply( df.a$y, function(y) which(df.b$y == y) ))
identical( inds.x, inds.y )
```

The last line gave `TRUE`, hence `df.a` is contained in `df.b`.

Now I wonder whether there is a more elegant - and possibly more efficient - way to answer this question?

This task also is easily extended to find the intersection between two given data frames, possibly based on only a subset of columns.

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe `all(mapply("%in%", df.a, df.b))`? Assuming they have same columns in the same order of course. Or a safer approach both for subset of columns and for correct column order could be `cols <- c("x", "y") ; all(mapply("%in%", df.a[cols], df.b[cols]))`

Comment: Does it matter if  pairing is recognized? Is `data.frame(a=1:4, b=5:8)` a subset of `data.frame(a=8:1, b=1:8)`. I would say no, but opinions may vary.

Comment: @DavidArenburg, I think this could be complicated by situations like is `c(2, 2)` contained in `c(2)`?

Comment: Assuming no duplicates in the data frame rows, you could use `merge` or `inner_join` from the dplyr package.

Comment: I think `dplyr::semi_join` can do what you want. `df.a <- data.frame( x=c(1:5,1), y=c(6:10,6) ); df.b <- data.frame( x=1:7, y=6:12 ); df.c <- data.frame( x=c(1:7, 1), y= c(6:12, 6) )`, `semi_join(df.b, df.a)` fails but `semi_join(df.c, df.a)` succeeds (up to a canonical ordering)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to hazard a guess at an answer.

I think `semi_join` from `dplyr` will do what you want, even taking into account duplicated rows.

First note the helpfile `?semi_join`:

> return all rows from x where there are matching values in y, keeping just columns from x.
>
> A semi join differs from an inner join because an inner 
>   join will return one row of x for each matching row of y, 
>   where a semi join will
>   never duplicate rows of x.

Ok, this suggests that the following should correctly fail:

```
df.a <- data.frame( x=c(1:5,1), y=c(6:10,6) )
df.b <- data.frame( x=1:7, y=6:12 )
identical(semi_join(df.b, df.a),  semi_join(df.a, df.a))
```

which gives `FALSE`, as expected since

```
> semi_join(df.b, df.a)
Joining by: c("x", "y")
  x  y
1 1  6
2 2  7
3 3  8
4 4  9
5 5 10
```

However, the following should pass:

```
df.c <- data.frame( x=c(1:7, 1), y= c(6:12, 6) )
identical(semi_join(df.c, df.a), semi_join(df.a, df.a))
```

and it does, giving `TRUE`.

The second `semi_join(df.a, df.a)` is required to get the canonical sorting on `df.a`.